# Namespace not recognised after adding MVC6 project dependency to class library project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, portable-class-library, class-library

I have created default MVC6 (.net framework 4.6.1) project. It contains only ValuesController. Also in the same solution I have added Class Library (.net framework 4.6.1).

When I added reference of  MVC6 project to class library I am not able to use any classes and namespaces.

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'mvc6test' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

Comment: Does the class library project build correctly? And its classes are public?

Comment: I have attached screenshot of the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class library project, make sure that the required **ASP.NET MVC** nuget package is added, same way as your web project itself.

[image]

It will add the various missing assemblies in your class library project, like System.Web.Mvc, System.Web.Razor etc.

*Note: Just wondering why you need to access this MVC project from within a class library. Normally it's the other way around.*

Comment: Thanks it has solved the issue. I am writing tests for controllers.

Comment: In that case, why not add a test project instead of a class library?